# C++ Linked List Traversal & Printing using a For loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, linked-list

Hey guys I'm having some trouble getting the for loop to work. myList is a linked list that's populated with numbers from a file and I'm trying to traverse it and print the current value and each next value in a sort of (current,next)-->(current,next) fashion. Count a variable that counted how many nodes that were present in my linked list.

```
linkedList test = myList;

for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
    cout << "(" << test.listHead->value << "," << test.listHead->next->value << ")-->";
    test.listHead = test.listHead->next;
}
```

For some reason the for loop fails to do anything or rather the code breaks right at the start of the for loop. If I get rid of the for loop and just copy and paste

```
    cout << "(" << test.listHead->value << "," << test.listHead->next->value << ")-->";
    test.listHead = test.listHead->next;
```

many times it will work as I desire, but I'd rather not do that. The for loop syntax looks right and if say count is 17, there should be 17 iterations of this until it reaches the end of the list.

edit:

Included are the source codes for the classes

```
class listNode{

public:
int value;
listNode* next;
friend class linkedList;


listNode():value(0),next(0) {
}
public:
~listNode(){
}; 

};


class linkedList{

public:
listNode* listHead;
listNode* spot;
int count;

linkedList()
{
    listHead->value = -9999;
}


bool isEmpty()
{
    return (listHead == NULL);  
}

void listInsert (int data)
{
    spot = findSpot(data);
    listNode* newNode = new listNode;
    newNode-> value = data;
    newNode-> next = spot->next;
    spot->next = newNode;

    cout << "inserted " << newNode->value << endl;  
}

listNode* findSpot (int data)
{
    spot = listHead;
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    while (spot->next != NULL && spot->next->value < data)
    {
   spot = spot->next;
     }

      if (spot->next->value == data)
        {
            cout << "The number: " << data << " already exists in the linked  list." << endl;
    spot = spot->next;

        }
    return spot;

}
```

Since I'm outputting to a file (using ofstream outfile). If I do

```
 outfile << "(" << test.listHead->value << "," << test.listHead->next->value << ")-->";
    test.listHead = test.listHead->next;
```

exactly 17 times (which is the size of the linked list and the count variable) it produces the whole list for me. But any time I try to initialize a

```
 listNode* test = myList.ListHead;
```

it will then refuse to run. It compiles fine, but the run just ends.

What I'm using in the main to populate the linkedList

```
  ifstream infile;
  infile.open((argv[1]));
  while (infile >> data)
  {

    myList.listInsert(data);
  }
```

Comment: 1. _Some trouble_ is the worst introduction you gan give with a question here. 2. Provide a [MCVE] and exactly provide any error messages you get verbatim in your question.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but the idiomatic way of writing that loop is `for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)`.

Comment: While you use the `spot` member variable in two different member functions, it's actually not a value that needs to be a member variable. You should make that variable a local variable in each function it's used.

Answer (score 1):

You actually modify the lists head pointer in the loop. You need to use a separate variable for the current node, initialized to the list head. You also need to check if the next pointer is valid before dereferencing it.

Like

```
auto currentNode = myList.listHead;
for (int i = 1; i <= count && currentNode != nullptr; ++i, currentNode = currentNode->next)
{
    if (currentNode->next != nullptr)
    {
        cout << "(" << currentNode->value << "," << currentNode->next->value << ")-->";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "(" << currentNode->value << ")-->";
    }
}
```

---

The actual problem is the `linkedList` class, which have one major problem leading to several cases of *undefined behavior*: You do not initialize the member variables of the class. Since they are not initialized their values will be *indeterminate* and using them in any way except to initialize them will lead to said UB.

You need to initialize `listHead` to a null pointer in the constructor, not dereference the uninitialized variable.

And if you are required to keep a dummy node at the end of the list (though I don't really see why) then you actually need to allocate a node.

Comment: For some reason I don't know if it's my list implementation or what but initiating a dummy/test node to myList.listHead always breaks. The way I had it in my original code works with the the initializing of two lists and moving the listHead seems to be the only way that works. The listNode object has a value (default 0) and a next (default NULL). The linkedList class has a listNode listHead (with value defaulted to -9999)

Comment: @user2444400 Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to include it?

Comment: I've edited the question with most of the information as best as I could.

Comment: We aren't required to make a dummy node at the end of the list, but rather set listHead to this dummy node at the beginning. The professor wants the output to be in this format "listHead -->(-9999, nextData)-->(data,  nextData)-> ...... --> (data,  -1)". The only way the code started working was when I dereferenced listHead's value to -9999. I initially had it as NULL but it refused to work.

Comment: @user2444400 You will always push new nodes before the dummy node (unless someone adds a value smaller than `-9999`) so it will always be at the end. Also, did you think that dereferencing a null pointer would be a good idea? A null pointer or an uninitialized pointer doesn't really make any difference, it will both lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: The way the findSpot function works won't the dummy node always be first and everything is pushed after it since the value is -9999? The output that my code puts out of the full linked list after grabbing all the values from the file is "listHead-->(-9999,8)-->(8,8)-->(8,12)-->(12,14)-->(14,29)-->(29,91)-->(91,91)-->(91,133)-->(133,322)-->(322,361)-->(361,538)-->(538,637)-->(637,702)-->(702,702)-->(702,900)-->(999,-1)"

Since listHead won't work (for me) without dereferencing it's value in the constructor, should I set the listNode's value to a -9999 in it's constructor?

Comment: @user2444400 A yes, misread that comparison. But reading that close lead me to find some other problems in `findSpot` (as you show it), namely what happens if the loop goes to the last node, i.e. when `spot->next` is `NULL`. Then you will dereference that `NULL` pointer in the condition.